# R: Replace column names with row values except where cells equal NA

Tags: r

I have a data frame extracted from a data base that contains different types of data (record types). The different record types have different column names which occupy the first three rows (including header). This data frame is made to be used in excel where you can easily filter out the data by choosing the correct record type.

Here I present small sample of my data frame which in reality contains many more columns (59) as well as rows (34000).

```
sample <- data.frame(X01RecordType=c("01HL","01CA","HH","HH","HH","HL"), X02Quarter=c(NA,NA,2,2,2,1),X05Gear=c(NA,NA,"KRA","KRA","KRA",NA),X06SweepLngt=c(NA,NA,35,35,-9,-9),
       X12Month=c("12SpecCodeType",NA,4,5,4,2), X13Day=c("13SpecCode",NA,26,5,25,160617), X22StatRec=c("22LngtCode","22CANoAtLngt","45G1",NA,NA,NA),X23Depth=c("23LngtClass","23IndWgt",41,NA,63,NA))
```

As you might see the cells which contain column names are preceded by an X and a number and then a text, e.g. X01RecordType. It would be very easy to replace column names with the first rows by using:

```
 colnames(df) <- df[1,]
```

However, as you can see some of the cells in the first two rows also contain NA-values. These NA-values indicate that the column names are the same for all record types, using the current header and therefore I would like to keep these. So really what I would like to do is replace the column names with the values of the first row (where record type header equals 01HL) except for NA-values.

If possible I would like to do this without using any external packages. Cells within the data may also contain NA-values and I would like to keep these rows so filtering out all columns containing NA is not an option if it doesn't only apply to the first row. Which is really the way I tried to approach this problem, but I can't figure out how.

I hope this is all the information required to help me out and thanks!

Comment: My understanding (leading to solution indicated below) is that when the value in the first row is NA, we just keep the original column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a simple loop:

```
for(c in 1:length(sample)) if(!is.na(sample[1,c])) colnames(sample)[c] = as.character(sample[1,c])
```

Comment: Thank you very much! As you might have noticed I'm still not very experienced in R, but this seems quite simple, and it works. It's also good that it's possible to just change the row number, since this might come in use later on. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Another option without a loop

```
colnames(sample)[!is.na(sample[1,])] <- sample[1,][!is.na(sample[1,])]

sample[1:2,]
#  01HL X02Quarter X05Gear X06SweepLngt 12SpecCodeType 13SpecCode   22LngtCode
#1 01HL         NA    <NA>           NA 12SpecCodeType 13SpecCode   22LngtCode
#2 01CA         NA    <NA>           NA           <NA>       <NA> 22CANoAtLngt
#  23LngtClass
#1 23LngtClass
#2    23IndWgt
```